# The Div's stack on top of each other

Tags: html, css

The second div stacks on top of the first div and the first div invisible
How can i position it below the first div

```css
.shop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.bell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop"></div>
<div class="bell">
        <img src="bell.png" alt="">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do ? :)

```css
.shop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.bell {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img{

width : 30%;

}
```

```html
<div class="shop"></div>
<div class="bell">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1289845/pexels-photo-1289845.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: no sir i just want the second div to appear under the other

Comment: But it already does that ? You want the red one to be on top of the black one ?

Comment: No the black one on top of the red one

Comment: But it already is on top of it. Look at my solution, scroll through my snippet. :)

Comment: For some reason the div's they stack side by side horizontally

Comment: the body tag has no style properties  btw

Comment: Perfect ! Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Hey Alex, while your answer works, it would be nice for possible future readers (and to actually help Ahim become better) if it would explain why this works or why Ahim's does not. E.g. link/explain how `display:flex` places elements

Comment: Absolutely, in most cases I do just that. But I was in a pretty big rush when I was writing that response. You are right :)